# Get multiple values out of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I searched a lot on the internet but I still can't find the right answer to my question. I am trying to "print" all the selected values out of multiple checkboxes on my html-page. However, this works only for integers and not for other values. Right now, I use to following code:

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="2" />
</div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="5" />
</div>
<span></span>
```

in combination with the following jquery code:

```
function calculate() {
var arr = $.map($('input:checkbox:checked'), function(e, i) {
    return +e.value;
});
$('span').text('the checked values are: ' + arr.join(','));
}

calculate();
$('div').delegate('input:checkbox', 'click', calculate);
```

The problem right now, is that I want to see all the values from the checkboxes, however, I do not want them to be integers, but they should have values like:

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Teamsport" />
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Individual sport" />
</div>
```

So that there will be an output like:
`the selected values are: Teamsport,Ballsport,etc..`

I think the problem should be in the Jquery code, but I am not very familiar with javascript and jquery, so I hope that someone can help me.

Comment: `.delegate` is deprecated, so you should use `.on` instead.

`$('div').on('click', 'input:checkbox', calculate);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hier is an example may help you

```js
$(':checkbox').change(function(){
    var liste2 = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
   $('span').text('the checked values are: ' + liste2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="1" />
   <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="2" />
</div>
<div>
   <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="3" />
   <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="4" />
   <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="5" />
</div>
<span></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is simply a typo in your code: this:

```
 return +e.value;
```

must be

```
 return e.value;
```

The prefix + is only defined for numbers, so javascript tries to convert the "Teamsport" into a number - which is NaN (not a number)

Answer (score 1):

Just return the `e.value` in your map function.

```js
function calculate() {
  var arr = $.map($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked'), function(e, i) {
    return e.value;
  });
  $('span').text('the checked values are: ' + arr.join(','));
  // console.log('the checked values are: ' + arr.join(','))
}

calculate();
$('div').on('click', 'input:checkbox', calculate);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Teamsport" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Individual sport" />
</div>

<span></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies here: `return +e.value;`

`+e.value` will return NaN for non-number values, in this case, String will be converted to NaN

```js
function calculate() {
  var arr = $.map($('input:checkbox:checked'), function(e, i) {
    return e.value; // +e.value will return NaN for String and non number values
  });
  $('span').text('the checked values are: ' + arr.join(','));
}

calculate();
$('div').delegate('input:checkbox', 'click', calculate);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="abc" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="pqr" />
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="xyz" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="lmn" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="ccc" />
</div>
<span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function calculate() {
var arr =[];
$('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    arr.push($(this).val());
});
$('span').text('the checked values are: ' + arr.join(','));
}

calculate();
$('div').delegate('input:checkbox', 'click', calculate);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="2" />
</div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="5" />
</div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Teamsport" />
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Individual sport" />
</div>
<span></span>
```